# Tracking event automated emails

Tags: civievent, civimail

Is there a way to track the open/bounce/etc info on the automated emails for events? I've never seen it, but wanted to verify. Thanks!

Comment: If the Transactional Mail extension doesn't already cover this it would be a good place to consider adding that feature

Comment: https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

Comment: Yay! Thanks. I will test that out.

Comment: Ok, I installed it onto the site. I created a test event with a receipt and registered for it. I got the receipt email; however, nothing was recorded on my record as far as an activity or mailing goes.